# Gulp Concat JS results in require is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, gulp, concatenation

I have project using gulp.

I am trying to get jquery, jquery ui and bootstrap into one file called vendor.js.

This works fine however when I run "gulp serve" to run the project fromthe  dist folder of the project i get the error

> ReferenceError: require is not defined
>   http://localhost:3000/assets/toolkit/scripts/vendor.js
>   Line 6

```
var jQuery = require('jquery');

gulp.task('vendor-js', function() {
       return gulp.src(['src/assets/toolkit/scripts/vendor/jquery.min.js', 
       'src/assets/toolkit/scripts/vendor/jquery-ui.js', 
       'src/assets/toolkit/scripts/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js' ])
       .pipe(concat('vendor.js'))
       .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/toolkit/scripts/'));
});
```

**Folder Structure**

```
dist\assets\toolkit\scripts

dist\assets\toolkit\styles

dist\assets\toolkit\images

dist\pages

index.html
```

Why is this the case? I have looked all over with no luck! I have seen similar issues but all relating to react?

Can anyone help?

Thanks

NIck

Comment: Can you please provide your `gulp serve` task details?

Comment: Added to original post

Comment: could you add your folder structure?

Comment: Can do but not sure how relevant it is? The js file joins and loads fine. I can see it and view it. Added structure

Comment: If i include each file seperatly in my html file it works fine other than jquery-ui which still throws the same error

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get this working eventually so I thought i would post my solution.

I reverted to using the built in toolkit.js file to require each dependency. In this case Jquery, Jquery Ui, Bootstrap Sass and Chart Js.

In my toolkit.js file i included

`window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('jquery-ui');
require('bootstrap-sass');
require('chart.js');`

This is then concatenated by my Gulp task.

The key is `window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');`

rather than

```
require('jquery');
```